# Gulp sass compilation working correctly on start up. Changed files will however be excluded

Tags: javascript, sass, gulp, gulp-sass

Whenever I start up my gulp process using 'gulp watch', my .scss files compile to a dist/css/main.css file correctly. The main.css file contains all (@)imports at this point. However, when I save changes to a file, the contents of said file will be excluded from my main.css. My setup used to work correctly, but after two months of development I find myself puzzled as to why this behaviour suddenly appeared.

My styles directory has two sub-directories: "styles/**/*.scss" 
My gulpfile: http://pastebin.com/sxuckitZ

Any other help on how to debug this problem is also greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It might have to do with how you have your watch task setup. You're using watch to do a watch function, which might be throwing it off. Here is a typical setup for my gulp file, which is a little more slim then yours:

```
// Theme Specific Variables
var theme = 'wheels-4-water';

// Include gulp
var gulp = require('gulp');

// Include Our Plugins
var jshint = require('gulp-jshint');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
var pngquant = require('imagemin-pngquant');
var minifyCss = require('gulp-minify-css');
// var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var zip = require('gulp-zip');
//var browserSync  = require( 'browser-sync' );

// Lint Task
gulp.task('lint', function() {
    return gulp.src([
        'src/js/*.js',
        '!src/js/global.min.js'
        ])
        .pipe(jshint())
        .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'));
});

// Compile Our Sass
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('src/scss/theme.scss')
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['last 2 versions'],
            cascade: false
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('src/css/'))
});

// Minimize CSS
gulp.task('minify-css', ['sass'], function() {
    return gulp.src([
        'src/css/*.css',
        '!src/css/*.min.css'
        ])
        .pipe(rename({
                suffix: '.min'
            }))
        .pipe(minifyCss({
            compatibility: 'ie8',
            aggressiveMerging: false,
            processImport: true
            }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('src/css/'));
});

// Concatenate & Minify JS
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    return gulp.src([
        './bower_components/slick-carousel/slick/slick.js',
      './bower_components/animsition/dist/js/animsition.js',
        'src/js/*.js',
        '!src/js/global.js',
        '!src/js/global.min.js'
        ])
        .pipe(concat('global.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('src/js'))
        .pipe(rename('global.min.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('src/js'));
});

// Minimize Images
gulp.task('images', function() {
    return gulp.src('src/images/src/*.{jpg,png}')
    .pipe(imagemin({
            progressive: true,
            svgoPlugins: [{removeViewBox: false}],
            use: [pngquant()]
        }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('src/images'));
});

// Copy Essential Files To Dist
gulp.task('copy', function() {
    gulp.src([
        // set up what you want to copy or ignore
        '!src/images/src/*',
        'src/**/*'
    ])
    .pipe(gulp.dest(theme));
});

// Watch Files For Changes
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch([
        'src/js/*.js',
        '!src/js/global.js',
        '!src/js/global.min.js'
        ], ['lint', 'scripts']);
    gulp.watch('src/scss/**/*.scss', ['minify-css']);
    gulp.watch([
      'src/css/*.css',
      '!src/css/theme.css',
      '!src/css/theme.min.css'
      ], ['minify-css']);
    gulp.watch('src/images/src/*.{jpg,png}', ['images']);
});

// Package a zip for theme upload
gulp.task('package', function() {
    return gulp.src(theme+'/**/*')
        .pipe(zip(theme+'.zip'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});

// Launch a development server
gulp.task( 'serve', function() {
    browserSync.init({
        proxy: "wheels:8888"
        // port: 3000
    });
});

// Default Task
gulp.task('default', ['lint', 'sass', 'minify-css', 'scripts', 'images', 'watch']);
```

Notice how in my watch task I am watching the directories inside that function. Good luck!